# canvas cleared once screen completed

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wanted to have a button to show a rectangle on a canvas.  But this is scrubbed after the script is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>

<br>depth = :  <input type="number" id="depthValue" name="depthValue"  value="2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculate()">


</form> 
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="background-color:#EE2"></canvas>


<script>

function calculate() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The rectangle appears, but it is immediately wiped out.

Whats happening?

Comment: is it showing when you press enter and then it disappears?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are submitting the form by hitting enter. So, you can think of it as if you were refreshing. So to solve this, stop the form from being submitted. Either inline with  the following `onsubmit="return false; "` or in javascript using this

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for that.   You are definitely on the right lines, although I might be implementing this wrongly.
I can see that I am running the anonymous java script after the onclick() function is called.    Even when I update the <form> declaration like this:

    <form onsubmit="submit()">

Comment: I may well have missed something obvious, or misunderstood your advice